# Does kevlar (composite materials ) have elasticity?

Tags: springs

Can we use kevlar, a composite material in leaf springs.  I mean does it have the properties which are essential for a leaf spring (like resistance to bending, elasticity)

if it has, are(properties)  they sufficient in case of heavy vehicle leaf springs?

Answer (score 1):

Of course. kevlar has high stiffness per weight so you would use it for a spring that needs to be stiff and light. It has somewhat less strain capability than glass fiber, which I suppose, along with cost, is why glass fiber composites seem to be selected for vehicle leaf springs.